# Task.Delay bugged or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, async-await

> EDIT: I was doing something wrong. Problem was timing code execution with datetime objects and outputing miliseconds instead of totalmiliseconds.

In short I have a new mvc4 project running on .net 4.5 with the following code in the homecontroller.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Int32[] Delays = new Int32[] { 1999, 500, 20 }; 
        List<String> result = new List<String>();

        var now = DateTime.Now;

        result.Add(String.Format("Started at: {0}", now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")));

        //TAKE 1
        result.Add("Take 1");
        await Task.WhenAll(Delays.Select(async x => result.Add(await Slow(x, now, Array.IndexOf(Delays, x), "take 1"))));

        //TAKE 2
        result.Add("Take 2");
        var tasks = Delays.Select((x, i) => Slow(x, now, i, "take 2")).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        result.AddRange(tasks.Select(x => x.Result));

        return View(result);
    }
```

My Slow method looks like this...

```
    private async Task<String> Slow(Int32 ms, DateTime dt, int i, String take)
    {
        Response.Write(String.Format("[{3}][index:{0}][delay:{2}] pre sleep - {1} <br />", i, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"), ms, take));

        await Task.Delay(ms);

        Response.Write(String.Format("[{3}][index:{0}][delay:{2}] after sleep - {1} <br />", i, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"), ms, take));

        var delayedtime = DateTime.Now;

        var diff = delayedtime - dt;

        return String.Format("Slept for : [{2}]{0} miliseconds. diff was : {1}", ms, diff.Milliseconds, take);
    }
```

The output looks like this ...

```
[take 1][index:0][delay:1999] pre sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:25.338 PM
[take 1][index:1][delay:500] pre sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:25.340 PM
[take 1][index:2][delay:20] pre sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:25.340 PM
[take 1][index:2][delay:20] after sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:25.368 PM
[take 1][index:1][delay:500] after sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:25.849 PM
[take 1][index:0][delay:1999] after sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:27.347 PM
[take 2][index:0][delay:1999] pre sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:27.347 PM
[take 2][index:1][delay:500] pre sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:27.347 PM
[take 2][index:2][delay:20] pre sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:27.347 PM
[take 2][index:2][delay:20] after sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:27.382 PM
[take 2][index:1][delay:500] after sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:27.861 PM
[take 2][index:0][delay:1999] after sleep - 06/21/2013 02:46:29.359 PM

Started at: 06/21/2013 02:46:25.336 PM
Take 1
Slept for : [take 1]20 miliseconds. diff was : 32
Slept for : [take 1]500 miliseconds. diff was : 513
Slept for : [take 1]1999 miliseconds. diff was : 11
Take 2
Slept for : [take 2]1999 miliseconds. diff was : 23
Slept for : [take 2]500 miliseconds. diff was : 525
Slept for : [take 2]20 miliseconds. diff was : 46
```

I'm quite puzzled by the fact that the delay of 1999miliseconds reports that it finished after 5 miliseconds where as the other two delays seem to work just fine.
I get this behaviour as soon as the delay parameter is above '999' miliseconds.

My question is if I'm doing something wrong, if the Delay is responding to a configuration I'm not aware of or if the Method is bugged.

Comment: `result.Add` is not thread-safe.  Return it to the task instead.

Comment: `async (x, index) => ...`

Comment: @SLaks I don't see any multi-threading in this code, so I think that should be fine. (Assuming `Index()` isn't called outside of the ASP.NET context, but I think that's a safe assumption to make.)

Comment: @svick Even so, it's still poor design.  It would be better for the task to just set that value as the result and then capture the collection of results through the return value of `WhenAll`.  It would be easier to code, clearer to the reader, and is a paradigm that doesn't have the risk of breaking if the tasks are run in different contexts.

Comment: @svick: You don't know what (or how many) threads `Task.Delay()` will call back on

Comment: @SLaks `Task.Delay()` returns a `Task` and `await`ing a `Task` always resumes on the current context (if there is any). So, if `Index()` is called under the ASP.NET context (and anything else doesn't make sense), then all the code in the method will execute on the same context. And the ASP.NET context ensures there is no parallelism, so the code is thread-safe.

Comment: @svick: Are you sure that ASP.Net's SyncContext is non-parallel?

Comment: @SLaks Considering the questions about deadlocks when combining `await` and `Wait()` in ASP.NET, yeah, I'm quite sure. Also, from [Stephen Cleary's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx): “If multiple operations complete at once for the same application, AspNetSynchronizationContext will ensure that they execute one at a time. They may execute on any thread, but that thread will have the identity and culture of the original page.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff.Milliseconds` measures the ms part of the TimeSpan. Perhaps you mean:

```
diff.TotalMilliseconds
```